# Change Orientation Of UIImage? Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimage, uikit, orientation

I am needing to change the image orientation. I have looked over stack overflow and not found anything to help. Please be sure to help!

I am using type UIImage, and would like to return a UIImage

There has been some of these questions put out, but I have found some in Objective C, or some bound not to work. Please let me know!!

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this function to change orientation [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624091-init)

> init(cgImage:scale:orientation:)
>
> Initializes and returns an image
>   object with the specified scale and orientation factors

**Declaration**

```
init(cgImage: CGImage, 
scale: CGFloat, 
orientation: UIImage.Orientation)
```

**How to use**

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "YourImageName")?.cgImage {
   YourImageView.image  = UIImage(cgImage: image, scale: UIScreen.main.scale, orientation: .right)
       }
```